# jQuery cycler/fader like on top10.com

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm looking for direction to a jQuery slider/cycler/fader plugin that will accomplish the functionality seen here under "Top 10 Mobile Phones"

http://top10.com/mobilephones/

I don't expect there will be an out of the box solution, but any advice, links, code would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers, I just used jCarousel and jCycle in the end, works perfect

Answer (score 0):

There are a million (well maybe less... but a lot..)

that link is done using jquery UI, without any cycle-like plugin,  look at their [mphomepage.js](http://top10.com/min/mphomepage.js) - the code is written quite clear inside.

You can pass it through some [js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)..